# PHP / Wordpress - get http requests from a page

Tags: php, performance, wordpress, curl

I have a test wordpress intallation on localhost and recently I noticed the administration pages load very slow.
Everytime I'm connected to the internet and open the /wp-admin pages it takes 14-15 seconds to load. This does not happen in the front end.

Is there any way to get info about all the http requests that are being made in the page, just like getting the # of queries (`get_num_queries`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EDIT: New Answer]** After OP clarification, here is the changed answer:

You can install xDebug and enable profiler in that. Here is the step-by-step tutorial on how to do that:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Testing_WordPress_Performance
This will tell you how much time spent in what part of code.

**Old Answer**:
I advise you to install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and get all the HTTP requests made, their responses and time taken.

Comment: i tried it and I can see only image requests, like the ones from gravatar.

http requests made with CURL for eg, are not visible...

Comment: No, cURL requests will not be visible through it. You should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: @Alex, I have changed the answer. Look at the new solution.

Comment: found out the problem. it was actually the object-cache plugin which was slowing down the site. and the weird thing is that it wasn't even enabled...
it seems that this plugin disables transients in wordpress, so the update check was made every time you opened a page, because there wasn't any transient set containing the last update info

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by http requests? You mean requested resources like images and such? Those you can see using a tool like [Firebug's "Net tab"](http://getfirebug.com/network).

Not sure whether there's much that can be done on that level, though. Wordpress *is* rather slow and fat - the fate of every web application that becomes more and more complex....

If you have no root privileges on the server your hosting runs on (to e.g. install an opcode cache like APC) the Wordpress back-ends slowness can be best helped by using Google Gears (see the "Turbo" button in your backend).

Comment: i'm sorry i should have mentioned - http requests to other sites from where wp fetches data. for eg. from time to time, WP checks for updates, and for this it makes a request to wp.org. When this happens the page takes a little more to load, since it waits for the data to be retrieved... 

My problem is that these kind of requests are made every time a page is loaded, not occasionally, so I want to find out to what site they are made :)

Comment: @Alex ah, I see! No, I don't know a generic function to find out the number of those. But I doubt whether they are the reason for the slowness... However, you should be able to turn off the constant checking for updates somehow, shouldn't you? Maybe there's even a plugin for that?

Answer (score 0):

if you use Chrome you can use the developer-view or you can install firebug for Firefox